# Is there anyway to revert my mac to HFS from APFS?

Tags: windows, mac, boot-camp, hfs+, apfs

Most of the time spent on my mac is spent on bootcamp or linux distros, but i have noticed that the main partition cannot be accessed by windows since it is APFS. Since the only way to access APFS is to pay money for drivers that should be free, is there a way to make the partition with MacOS HFS? is it even supported by modern MacOS? *I am using the built in SSD on a 2017 macbook pro*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely OS-dependant.

- Up to High Sierra the answer is yes [though any time you re-install the OS it may once more upgrade you to APFS if you have an SSD].
- From Mojave onwards the answer is 'only if you force it'.
  Mojave will boot from HFS+ but will not install to it, it will always convert to APFS at install. You have to manually revert the format afterwards. This is not a 'safe' operation & cannot be done without 3rd party tools* [& a good backup strategy].
- From Catalina onwards you will have a hard struggle getting HFS to understand how the dual volume OS/Data works - avoid even attempting this.

As this is likely to get even harder from Big Sur, I'd seriously consider investing in a 3rd party Windows app that supports APFS - such as [Paragon APFS for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/apfs-windows/)

Note: There is no "should be free" in the software world. There's 'is free' because someone worked hard & gave away the results, or 'is paid' because the solution remains proprietary. Same applies to writing NTFS on Mac.

*Again, Paragon have this one covered. Yes, it's a paid solution. No, I have no afilliation ;)